# Increasing Number of VMs decreases Cassandra Throughput. What can be reason?

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-2.1, ycsb

I am using YCSB benchmarking tool to benchmark Cassandra cluster.
I am varying the number of Virtual machines in the cluster.
I am using 1 physical host and I am using 1,2,3,4 virtual machines for benchmarking(as shown in attached figure).

The generated workload is same all the time Workload C 10,000,00 operations, 10,000 records
Each VM has 2 GB RAM, 20GB drive

Cassandra - 1 seed node, endpoint_snitch - gossipproperty
Keyspace YCSB - Replication factor 3,

The problem is that when I increase the number of virtual machines in the cluster, the throughput decreases. What can be the reason?

By definition, by increasing compute resources(i.e virtual machines), the cluster should offer better performance, but the opposite is happening as shown in attached figure. Kindly explain what can be the probable reason for this? I am writing my thesis on this topic but I am unable to figure out the reason for this, please help, I will be grateful to you.

Throughput observed by varying number of VMs in Cassandra cluster:
[image: Throughput observed by varying number of VMs in cassandra cluster]

Comment: How not to benchmark C* -- http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/how-not-to-benchmark-cassandra

Answer (score 4):

Very likely hitting a disk IO bottleneck. Especially with non ssd drives this is completely expected. Unless you have dedicated disk/cpu per vm the competition for resources will cause contention like this. Also 2gb per vm is not enough to do any kind of performance benchmark with Cassandra since the minimum recommended JVM heap size is 8gb.

Answer (score 3):

Cassandra is great at horizontal scaling (nearly linear), but that doesn't mean that simply adding VMs to one physical host will increase throughput - a single VM on the physical host will have less contention for resources (disk, cpu, memory, network) than 4, so it's likely one VM would perform better than 4.

By definition, if you **WERE** increasing resources, you SHOULD see it perform better - but you're not, you're simply adding **contention** to existing resources. If you want to scale cassandra, you need to test it with additional physical resources - more physical machines, not more VMs on the same machine.

Finally, as Chris Lohfink mentions, your VMs are too small to do meaningful tests - 8GB JVM heap is recommended, with another 8GB of vm page cache to support reads - running Cassandra with less than 16G of RAM is typically non-ideal in production.

You're trying to test a jet engine (a distribute database designed for hundreds or thousands of physical nodes) with a gas station level equipment - your benchmark hardware isn't viable for a real production environment, so your benchmark results aren't meaningful.